# Treeview node disable

Tags: asp.net

I have a treeview and the nodes are populated from a table . I want to disable some particular node according to the name of that node

Comment: Can you explain more on what you are having difficulty with?

Comment: The root nodes are populated from the table I want to cancel the expansion or disable that root node when i click that node

Answer (score 3):

Please try this code:

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are getting the data from your table then building your treeview by iterating your data and creating a treenode for that row and adding to the treeview.

In which case when you create the treeviewnode you can enable/disable at that point.